# Swift View not updating when Observed Object changes

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have some code like this:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
 @Published var data = dbContent

 init(){
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
  db.collection("collection").document(userID).addSnapshotListener {
  //getting data from DB and storing them as objects by appending them to data
  }
 }
}
```

```
struct 1View: View {
 @ObservedObject var myData: Data = Data()

 var body: some View {
  2View(myData: self.myData)
  3View(myData: self.myData)
 }
}
```

```
struct 2View: View {
 @State var myData: Data

 var body: some View {
  List(){
   ForEach(data.count){ data in
    Text(data)
   }.onDelete(perform: deleteData) //Deletes the item
  }
 }
}
```

```
struct 3View: View {
 @State var myData: Data

 var body: some View {
  List(){
   ForEach(data.count){ data in
    Text(data)
   }.onDelete(perform: deleteData) //Deletes the item
  }
 }
}
```

Now the issue is, that I can delete the the item in the 2View. This is then also shown and I implemented the functionality that it deletes the Item in the DB as well. 
So the DB data gets altered but this is not shown in the 3View until I refresh it by e.g. revisiting it.

I have no idea what the cause is. Maybe I got a wrong understanding of `@Published` and `ObservedObject` ?

Comment: Did you assign dbContent?

Comment: ```dbContent``` gets "overwritten" by the custom object that I create when getting the data from the Database. Maybe here lies the error? I have a snapshotListener in this method and the goal of this method is to assign the newly created object to ```dbContent```. Does this work like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@State` means that the view owns the data and manages the state. Try using `@ObservedObject` in your child views as well. Here is an example:

**Model**

```swift
struct Book: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var title: String
  var author: String
  var numberOfPages: Int

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case author
    case numberOfPages = "pages"
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```swift
class BooksViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var books = [Book]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    fetchData()
  }

  deinit {
    unregister()
  }

  func unregister() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
    }
  }

  func fetchData() {
    unregister()

    listenerRegistration = db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.books = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Book? in
        return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Book.self)
      }
    }
  }

  func deleteBooks(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    self.books.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
  }

}
```

**Views**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SampleView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = BooksViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      InnerListView1(viewModel: viewModel)
      InnerListView2(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
  }
}

struct InnerListView1: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: BooksViewModel

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.books) { book in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(book.title)
            .font(.headline)
          Text(book.author)
            .font(.subheadline)
          Text("\(book.numberOfPages) pages")
            .font(.subheadline)
        }
      }
      .onDelete { indexSet in
        self.viewModel.deleteBooks(at: indexSet)
      }
    }
  }

}


struct InnerListView2: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: BooksViewModel

  var body: some View {
      List(viewModel.books) { book in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(book.title)
            .font(.headline)
          Text(book.author)
            .font(.subheadline)
          Text("\(book.numberOfPages) pages")
            .font(.subheadline)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing I noticed when trying to reproduce your issue: if you're using `CodingKeys` (which you only need to do if your the attribute names on the Firestore documents are different from the attribute names on your Swift structs), you need to make sure that the `id` is also included. Otherwise, `id` will be nil, which will result in the `List` view not being abel to tell the items apart.

Comment: Sadly this did not do the trick. But thank you for the efforts!

Comment: @Simon, I've expanded the sample - please give it another try. I've just tried this, and it works as intended.